# Replacing data.frame by data_frame() and cbind by bind_cols() from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sp

I'm trying to rewrite a portion of my code with the latest features from `dplyr` by replacing `data.frame()` by `data_frame()` and `cbind()` with `bind_cols()`:

```
library(rgeos)
library(dplyr)

mc <- montreal %>%
  gCentroid(byid=TRUE) %>%
  data.frame %>%
  cbind(., name = montreal[["NOM"]])
```

When I try to replace `data.frame` by `data_frame` I get:

```
Error: data_frames can only contain 1d atomic vectors and lists
```

And when I try to replace `cbind` by `bind_cols` I get:

```
Error: object at index 2 not a data.frame
```

Would there be a way to make this work ?

Here, `montreal` is a SpatialPolygonsDataframe:

GEOJSON file: http://elm.bi/limadmin.json

```
montreal <- readOGR("data/limadmin.json", "OGRGeoJSON")
```

Comment: Your `dput` output is not able to be reconstructed because of the S4 objects.  You may want to try the solution to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466599/dputting-an-s4-object) and return with reproducible data.

Comment: Could you provide the lines of code to create it from scratch instead of `dput`?

Comment: I edited the post accordingly

Comment: I can't read your file, but I think the errors say it all. Have you tried `bind_cols(., data_frame(name=montreal[["NOM"]])` on the last line?

Comment: How about `mc <- montreal %>%  gCentroid(byid=TRUE) %>%  data.frame %>%  bind_cols(., data_frame(name=montreal[["NOM"]]))`

Comment: It works. Should I conclude I cannot get rid of `data.frame` because the initial input is not a supported format to `data_frame` ?

Comment: To my limited grasp of it, yes. And, supported formats are `data.frame`s or `list of data.frame`s, hence the speed improvement.

Comment: `data_frame()` isn't the same as `data.frame()`. `data.frame()` does lots and lots of things. `data_frame()` does only one - it creates one column for each input.

Comment: @hadley After reading thoroughly the vignette on data_frame(), it is now crystal clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome - glad the vignette helped :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I ended up running `microbenchmark` on the two approaches because it felt a bit odd using:

```
mc <- montreal %>% 
    gCentroid(byid=TRUE) %>% 
    data.frame %>% 
    bind_cols(., data_frame(name=montreal[["NOM"]]))
```

I tried with two different datasets:

```
world <- readOGR("data/world.json", "OGRGeoJSON")

wmbm = microbenchmark(
  base = world %>% 
    gCentroid(byid=TRUE) %>% 
    data.frame %>% 
    cbind(., name=world[["name"]]),
  dplyr = world %>% 
    gCentroid(byid=TRUE) %>% 
    data.frame %>% 
    bind_cols(., data_frame(name=world[["name"]])),
  times=100
)
```

Microbenchmark results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  base 13.78396 14.08301 14.21357 14.12023 14.16435 20.04362   100
 dplyr 13.87098 14.10680 14.25245 14.14330 14.18020 17.63248   100
```

[image]

```
montreal <- readOGR("data/limadmin.json", "OGRGeoJSON")

lmbm = microbenchmark(
  base = montreal %>% 
    gCentroid(byid=TRUE) %>% 
    data.frame %>% 
    cbind(., name=montreal[["NOM"]]),
  dplyr = montreal %>% 
    gCentroid(byid=TRUE) %>% 
    data.frame %>% 
    bind_cols(., data_frame(name=montreal[["NOM"]])),
  times=100
  )
```

Microbenchmark results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  base 1.597957 1.628723 1.736709 1.651747 1.686554 3.091738   100
 dplyr 1.621092 1.642678 1.756978 1.659041 1.739707 3.751866   100
```

[image]

No real conclusion here. Even though it seems a bit slower, I will stick with the `dplyr`-esque solution for consistency, I guess.